# Python convert simple integer list to Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an int element list.

I want to change that list to a Fibonacci series sequence.

```
data = [1,0,2,4,5]
output_data = [1,1,3,7,12]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
import itertools as it

data = [1,0,2,4,5]
output = list(it.accumulate(data))

# [1, 1, 3, 7, 12]
```

The default binary function it applies is summation (more precisely, `operator.add`).

Comment: this is very good answer :tup

Answer (score 1):

```py
import itertools as it

data = [1,0,2,4,5]

l = [e for e in it.accumulate(data)]

print(l)
# output_data = [1,1,3,7,12]
```